# SQL code to get the top 100 addresses closest to each other. Travelling salesman problem?

Tags: sql, latitude-longitude

I have a list of qualified addresses with longitudes and latitudes, I want to select the top 100 addresses that are closest to each other. What code can I use to achieve that?

Thank you so much,

Comment: what do you mean by "top", are you sorting on a value?

Comment: it's possible a GIS application would be able to hand this better with some measure of the density of the addresses.

Comment: Cross join the table onto itself into a cte (or temp table or table variable), and in that join create 2 new columns which are the absolute value of the difference between long and lat (diff_log, diff_lat).  Then select top 100 from the cte ordering by the diff_long, diff_lat